# Python Command to remove line breaks from txt file

Tags: python

I am trying to remove lines of text from a txt file through python. I have looked everywhere and found many answers, but still can't get it. So far I have this:

```
os.system("grep /n /home/pi/Documents/difference.txt >> /home/pi/grep1.txt")
```

difference.txt contains this:

```
192.168.0.***
192.168.0.***
192.168.0.***
192.168.0.***
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
192.168.0.*** 192.168.0.*** 192.168.0.*** 192.168.0.***
```

But grep1.txt is empty.

Sorry if this question has alredy been asked! :-)

**EDIT**
It can be shell or python, I don't care.

Comment: Read the file line by line and join them together?

Comment: This looks more like a problem with using `grep` than one with Python.

Comment: What's up with the `/n`?

Comment: Load the file (if not too big) as a whole string and call `replace` on it to replace line endings with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use python, one way might be:

```
with open('difference.txt', 'r') as f:
    c = f.read()

with open('grep1.txt', 'wb') as f:
    # python2.7
    # f.write(''.join(c).replace('\n', ' '))

    # in python3.x:
    f.write(bytes(''.join(c).replace('\n', ' '),  'utf-8'))
```

produces:

```
$ cat grep1.txt
192.168.0.*** 192.168.0.*** 192.168.0.*** 192.168.0.***
```

If you want a unix tool, maybe `tr` -- translate characters:

```
cat difference.txt | tr '\n' '\0'
```

Comment: I get the error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' on  f.write(' '.join(c).replace('\n', ' '))

Comment: you're using `python3`? cast the `f.write()` parameters to `bytes()` and encode. see updated answer